# How to configure Spring Ws with keystore and trustore?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, spring-ws, jsse

Where do I place these commands in Spring Ws

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=tomcat.keystore
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=tomcat
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=tomcat.keystore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=tomcat
-Djavax.net.debug=SSL
```

Do i have to place it as arguments or specify the properties in some class.I have Spring WS annotation based configuration can I configure the properties in the application itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution I can either set the properties using

```
System.setproperty("-Djavax.net.debug","SSL");
```

Or I can specify these arguments with tomcat7 when the server starts running.
Go to eclipse->right click on project->click run configuration->select tomcat ->select arguments->paste the property->click apply 
And then restart tomcat